# Read multiple values inside a node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

hi all am trying to read a xml document using linq.am struck with a problem a node has two values in the same name how can i get those two values. am able to get only the first using this code.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Orders.xml");
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Order")
           select new
           {
               OrderID = item.Element("OrderID").Value,
               POnumber = item.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber").Value,
               OrderDate = item.Element("OrderPlacedDate").Value,
               PFirstName = item.Element("purchasingContact").Element("FirstName").Value,
               Pid= item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails").Element("ProductsId").Value
           };
```

am able to get only product id 34 how can i get the another one too?Please help

```
<Order>
    <OrderID>123</OrderID>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>12</PurchaseOrderNumber>
    <OrderPlacedDate>12/23/2012</OrderPlacedDate>
    <PurchasingContact>
     <FirstName>test</FirstName>
    </PurchasingContact>        
    <CurrentOrderDetails>
       <ProductsId>34</ProductsId>
       <OrderQuantity>2</OrderQuantity>
       <ProductsId>35</ProductsId>
       <OrderQuantity>2</OrderQuantity>
    </CurrentOrderDetails>
</Order>
<Order>
    .......
</Order>
```

Comment: I see no reason why this should return multiple values: `Pid= item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails").Element("ProductsId").Value`

Comment: @BenjaminToueg am trying to get both ProductsId (34 and 35) in  <CurrentOrderDetails>.Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Orders.xml");
 var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Order")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = item.Element("OrderID").Value,
                POnumber = item.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber").Value,
                OrderDate = item.Element("OrderPlacedDate").Value,
                PFirstName = item.Element("purchasingContact").Element("FirstName").Value,
                Pids = item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails").Elements("ProductsId").Select(e => e.Value).ToList()
            };
```

But to be honest - you should consider changing the XML structure. `CurrentOrderDetails` should look more like that:

```
<CurrentOrderDetails>
    <Product id="34" quantity="2" />
    <Product id="35" quantity="2" />
</CurrentOrderDetails>
```

or

```
<CurrentOrderDetails>
    <Product>
        <Id>34</Id>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Id>35</Id>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Product>
</CurrentOrderDetails>
```

This would make it easier to get product ID and it's quantity together.

Comment: Works like a charm..how can i iterate if the xml is in the second format that you have specified can you help me

Comment: you can get a list of all products like that: `Products = item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails").Elements("Product").Select(p => new { Id = (int)p.Element("Id"), Quantity = (int)p.Element("Quantity")}).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

```
from o in doc.Descendants("Order")
let contact = o.Element("purchasingContact")
let details = o.Element("CurrentOrderDetails")
select new {
    OrderID = (int)o.Element("OrderID"),
    POnumber = (int)o.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber"),
    OrderDate = (DateTime)o.Element("OrderPlacedDate"),
    PFirstName = (string)contact.Element("FirstName"),
    Pids = details.Elements("ProductsId").Select(e => (int)e).ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the Pids as an array within your structure, you could have

```
Pids = item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails")
    .Elements("ProductsId")
    .Select(e => e.Value).ToArray()
```

If you want all your entries as a flat list, the way to go would be

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Order")
           from product in item.Element("CurrentOrderDetails").Elements("ProductsId")
                     select new
                     {
                         OrderID = item.Element("OrderID").Value,
                         POnumber = item.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber").Value,
                         OrderDate = item.Element("OrderPlacedDate").Value,
                         PFirstName = item.Element("purchasingContact")
                             .Element("FirstName").Value,
                         Pid = product.Value
                      };
```

By the way: the XML model should have a surrounding element around the productsid and orderquantity explicitly modelling an order row. That would be more expressive and intuitive.